# How to wrap words in HTML document without attributes and tag names

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri, text-processing

I have an HTML document that has long words:

```
<div>this is a veeeeeeeeeeeerryyyyyyyyloooongwoooord<img src="/fooooooooobaaar.jof" ></div>
```

I want to word-wrap it without cutting the tags or its attributes:

```
<div>this is a veeeeeeeeeeeerryyyyy yyyloooongwoooord<img src="/fooooooooobaaar.jof" ></div>
```

Also, it's possible that I will not have any HTML tag at all.

I tried Nokogiri, but it inserts a paragraph in tagless input, and wraps the whole response with an HTML document, which is not my intention.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
require "Nokogiri"
class String
  def wrap()
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(self)
    doc.at("body").traverse do |p|
      if p.is_a?(Nokogiri::XML::Text)
        input = p.content
        p.content = input.scan(/.{1,25}/).join(" ")
      end
    end
    doc.to_s # I want only the wrapped string, without the head/body stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the code you've written first. That gives us something to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I think using Nokogiri::XML(self) instead of Nokogiri::HTML(self) will help you.

Comment: Not if it's truly HTML. Nokogiri uses a more strict parser for XML than it does for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a starting point for you:

```
require 'nokogiri'

max_word_length = 30
html = '<div>this is a veeeeeeeeeeeerryyyyyyyyloooongwoooord<img src="/fooooooooobaaar.jof" ></div>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)

doc.search('text()').each do |n|
  n.content = n.content.split(' ').map { |l|
    if (l.size > max_word_length)
      l = l.scan(/.{1,#{ max_word_length }}/).join("\n")
    end
    l
  }.join(' ')
end

puts doc.to_html
# >> <div>this is a veeeeeeeeeeeerryyyyyyyyloooong
# >> woooord<img src="/fooooooooobaaar.jof">
# >> </div>
```

Comment: doesn't work if you fave htmlentities in the source, for example &shy;

Comment: Then process them first. This wasn't a canned solution, it's a starting point.